# Rendering dinamically GenericHtmlControl/Literal merged with an Asp.net Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-4

My Environment is: ASP.NET 4.62 / C# / Boostrap 4 framework

My application renders bootstrap 4 menu from database query.
I've a div in aspx page

```
<div id="myNav" runat="server"></div>
```

and i add code behind as

```
 myNav.InnerHtml = mystr.ToString()
```

Now i need to integrate in the menu a LoginView asp.net control.
Obviously if i add

```
<asp:LoginView id="LoginView1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
```

as string, the browser will receive a string a not renders a control ASP.NET.

I need to render something like this

```
....previous items menu
<asp:LoginView id="LoginView1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
<AnonymousTemplate>
<ul class='nav navbar-nav ml-auto'> 
<li class='nav-item'>
<a class='nav-link' href='../../Account/Login.aspx'><span class='fas fa-user'> 
</span>Login</a> </li>
<li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='~/Account/Login.aspx'>
<span class='fas fa-sign-in-alt'></span> Login</a> </li> </ul>
</AnonymousTemplate>
<LoggedInTemplate>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav ml-auto'> 
    <li class='nav-item'>
    <a class='nav-link' href='~/Account/Login.aspx'><span class='fas fa-user'></span></a> 
     </li>
    <li class='nav-item'>   
     <span class="myText">Hallo, </span><a runat="server" class="username" 
      href="~/Account/Manage.aspx" title="Profile">
        <asp:LoginName runat="server" CssClass="username" />
        </a>!
       <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Exit" 
       LogoutPageUrl="~/Logout.aspx" />
    </li> </ul>     
 </LoggedInTemplate>
 </asp:LoginView>
...closing boostrap menu tag
```

Which is best way to resolve this type of problem ?

I need to change approach ?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the HTML at the server side; that is a possibility, but as you see, it makes it hard to combine this with ASP.NET server controls.

It would be better to put the HTML on the .aspx-page. I understand that your database knows which menu-items should be visible. And that you want to add 1 additional item, where users can login.
You could use (for example) a GridView with one column.

```
<Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
         <div>Your HTML here </div> 
         <div><%# Item.SomeProperty %></div>
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Use the data from your database to render one 'row' per menuitem in the grid. You can customize the TemplateField so it contains the bootstrap-layout as you need it.

It might also be possible to keep your current approach. I think then you should at least *not* create your opening and closing bootstrap-menu tags in the code-behind. You should put those tags on the .aspx-page itself, the structure would then be:

```
<opening tag bootstrap menu>
<div id="myNav" runat="server"></div>
<asp:LoginView id="LoginView1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled"> ... </ ..>
<closing tag bootstrap menu>
```